# How to groupby every n elements in array in Julia

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by, julia

I have an array in Julia that looks like this:

```
10-element Array{Float64,1}:
 68.0
 68.0
 68.0
 68.0
 68.0
 78.0
 78.0
 68.0
 78.0
 68.0
```

I want to group this array every n elements and take the mean. In python, I would simply do the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(array)
n = 5
df.groupby(df.index // n).mean().tolist()
```

Which would give me:

```
[68, 75]
```

How to I replicate in Julia?

Comment: in your result `75` seems to be incorrect - it should be `74` I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Julia you can do it with built-in packages like this:

```
julia> using Statistics

julia> map(mean, Iterators.partition(array, n))
2-element Vector{Float64}:
 68.0
 74.0
```

or e.g.

```
julia> mean.(Iterators.partition(array, n))
2-element Array{Float64,1}:
 68.0
 74.0
```