# Compute row sums and column sums efficiently in Julia

Tags: arrays, memory, julia, reshape

Consider the code below

```
test_vector = 1:100
group_size = 10
num_groups = div(length(test_vector), group_size)
res_1 = sum(reshape(test_vector, group_size, num_groups), dims=1)
res_2 = sum(reshape(test_vector, group_size, num_groups), dims=2)
```

This code does what I want. Essentially, I am reshaping the vector into a 10x10 matrix, and compute the row sums and column sums. However, is there a way to accomplish this more efficiently? I know that `reshape` allocates memory every time. I intend to repeat this code multiple times in my program (i.e. I will write it as a function with `test_vector` and `group_size` being arguments, and call it many times). What is the most efficient way (in terms of speed and subsequently memory allocation) to accomplish this?

I tried to adapt the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66318580/how-to-groupby-every-n-elements-in-array-in-julia) but it doesn't quite accomplish what I want. Can I get a hint? Thank you.

Comment: How are you measuring allocations? The type of `reshape(test_vector, group_size, num_groups)` is not `Matrix` but `Base.ReshapedArray{Int64, 2, UnitRange{Int64}, Tuple{}}`.

Comment: Here's a small usability tip about `reshape`: it automatically calculates a missing dimension, so you can write `reshape(test_vector, group_size, :)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Julia `reshape` is not allocating.

```
julia> v1 = rand(100);

julia> @allocated v2 = reshape(v1, 10, 10)
96
```

(only the information about reshaping is stored, data is not copied)

This means that mutating the original mutates the `reshape`:

```
julia> v1[1] = 99; @show v2[1,1];
v2[1, 1] = 99.0
```

Indeed both variables point to the same place in memory:

```
julia> Int(pointer(v1)) == Int(pointer(v2))
true
```

If you want to have a real copy you would need to have done

```
julia> @allocated v3 = collect(reshape(v1, 10, 10))
992
```

sums benchmark the same whether you use `v2` or `v3`, hence `reshape` is the most efficient option for you (unless you perhaps write some dedicated loop and SIMD it).

Comment: Thank you. Do you have an example that writes a loop and uses SIMD?

Comment: You can write a custom loop - could be faster. Use `@inbounds` and consider adding `@simd` - see examples at https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/  `@simd` will help or not but it is worth trying